# How To Hide All But One Character From A Password Field

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So I have done quite a bit of research on this question, but have found no definitive answer. Essentially, on a users' account page, I want to be able to display their password with all but the first letter hidden. It would look like this:

> Password: p*******

The password is going to be pulled as a normal string from a database, then needs to be hidden before being placed into the appropriate text field. How can I accomplish this in javascript?

**Added Information**

- I would like to have the password stored in a normal `<p>` or `<h3>` Tag--not editable by the user until requested (I'll handle that).
- All passwords are currently being stored in a `firebase` database.

Comment: In what element you are intending to display this masked password? `text field`? as in `input text`? and when how you are getting this? through `ajax`? or normal page load?

Comment: Would you like the * characters to hold a value? That would add a greater challenge.

Comment: For what it's worth, storing plain-text passwords is generally considered to be absolutely wrong. If it's worth having a password-protected system, it's worth storing passwords correctly (hashed with bcrypt or scrypt or something). Maintain the first character separately if you want, though that doesn't seem like a particularly good idea either.

Comment: And how in the world is this worth seven upvotes?

Comment: I agree with @Pointy, it is always a good idea to encrypt user information when possible especially in a database.

Comment: @Pointy I've noticed some pretty dramatic voting going on in several threads today... seems odd indeed

Comment: Not only should you hash (not encrypt, HASH) passwords in your database, but if you ever have to display a password, or even one letter of it, you must use a server side language, definitely not JavaScript.

Comment: @GuruprasadRao Text Field and normal page load.

Comment: Please clarify if this is purely a matter of **displaying** the password with all but first character replaced with an asterisk, or you want to have a password input field which behaves in this way.

Comment: @Pointy I agree with you, the passwords are stored properly, as I am retrieving them from `firebase`, I know what I can do! I can pull get the password itself temporality, split it at the first letter, find the length of the entire password itself  and replace the remainder of the password with the asterisks... it would be a bit safer?

Comment: @AntoineB just being pedantic but JavaScript is a server side language thanks to NodeJs. But its this shouldn't be done on the client.

Comment: @ste2425 Just being pedantic but the fact that NodeJS is JavaScript doesn't mean that JavaScript is NodeJS. So, no, JavaScript isn't a server side language. Now I understand what you mean and I didn't included NodeJS in my comment since he's not using NodeJS but is doing it client-side.

Comment: @AntoineB yes your right, the context in which a language is used is the important part.

Comment: IMO, this is a horrible idea that compromises your user's security, even if only done server side. First, longer password are more secure. You are essentially shortening the user's password by 1 character which can be going from hours of searching to minutes. Second, you are telling the user (or hacker) what the first letter is. Using a dictionary to look up passwords, this is essentially telling them where to start looking. If I handed you a 5000 page dictionary and said my password is in there, but then told you to look under "P" I've now cut your search down by quite a lot.

Comment: @Ethan no. **Nobody** should be able to ever recover a properly stored password. They should be hashed with an industry-standard password hash. Once that's done, the original password should be thrown away and never persisted to any database.

Comment: @Ethan If you kno what youre doing, dont store users password in plain text! If this is just testing on a localhost, see answers below

Comment: Third, you are showing the user/hacker the length of the password. Imagine that dictionary I gave you before and I now told you that the word is only 8 letters long. Cutting the list down to maybe a few hundred at best.

Comment: @Ethan [read this, probably twice](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm)

Comment: Ironically, [lots](http://passwordmasking.com/) [of](http://www.zdnet.com/article/we-need-to-stop-masking-passwords/) [people](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/stop-password-masking/) think that masking passwords in password input fields is a bad idea. So, bottom line: you cannot show users their passwords or any part of them because properly-implemented security renders that impossible, and masking passwords in sign-in forms is probably not necessary (or should be optional).

Answer (score 4):

As many others have stated, it is not advisable to do this with JavaScript. Doing this with JavaScript requires the password to be sent with plain text which is visible to anyone snooping on the user's network. It would be much better to hide the characters on the server first and, then, send the result to the browser. Doing it entirely with JavaScript is a HUGE security risk. Think carefully before doing it this way.

This answer assumes you want to a variable to store the user's actual password for later use. The variable `password` holds the actual password in it. The textbox only holds the first letter while all other characters are represented by `*`.

```js
window.addEventListener('load',function(){
  var passwordBox = document.getElementById('password');
  var password;
  passwordBox.addEventListener('input',function(){
    password = this.value;
    this.value = '';
    var characters = password.split('');
    if(characters.length > 0){
        this.value = characters[0];
        for(var i = 1; i < characters.length; i++){
            this.value += '*';
        }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="password">
```

Comment: @Jonasw Could you explain what you meant by that statement?

Comment: You are modifying the actual value, therefore, you cannot recover the real password in order to "use" it.

Comment: @www139 you declare `password` outside that event handler with `var`, and then you *redeclare* `password` *inside* the handler.

Comment: @Pointy oh, yeah. Oops, I'll remove that `var`. I forgot to make it write to the global variable.

Comment: @PabloMatiasGomez You can, but he doesnt

Comment: Now I understand. I'm giving it another shot....

Answer (score 3):

**String masking**

If you simply have a password string, and want the string with asterisks:

```
function mask(str){
 return str.split("").map((e,i)=>i?"*":e).join("");
}
```

Use like this:

```
alert(mask("supersecretpass"));
```

**Input masking**

```
window.onload=function(){
   var passelem=;//add your input elem here
   var password="";//the real password
   passelem.oninput=function(){
      if(password.length>this.value.length){
      //user pressed backspace...
      var arr=password.split("");
      arr.pop();//remove last char
      password=arr.join("");
      return;
      }
       password+=this.value.split("").pop();//add added char to password
       this.value=password.split("")[0];//add first char
       for(i=1;i<password.length;i++){
           this.value+="*";//add the *
        }
    };
   //kill arrows
  document.onkeydown=function(e){
   if(e.wich==33||e.wich==34){
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
   }
  };
 };
```

Like www139s answer, but with correct password output...

Comment: Thank you. After studying your answer, you are more correct than I am. However, in your code, you assume that when the user presses the backspace key, they deleted the last character. This isn't correct. However, it is much better than mine. I am working on a new answer. I think keycodes are the only way around this.

Comment: Why isnt that correct if the input is a** and the password abcd, the user removed a char

Comment: What if the user's caret in the box is not at the end of the text box? When the user deletes something, it will not be the last character. Your code assumes that the user's caret is always located at the end of the text box. It is nearly impossible to answer this question. The only way would be to actually read the location of the caret which is extremely complicated. Browser support is also very limited.

Comment: Thats a point (user could also mark+ctrl+x)  =>impossible. My answer works for most cases, you only need to block mouse + arrow keys

Comment: What if the user uses the mouse to click a new caret location. Again, there is no good client-side solution to this question. The only reliable method would be to simulate a real text box. I.E. create your own text box and hard code it yourself. Very complicated and near impossible. It would take so much work!

Comment: by the way +1 ;) Your answer is better than mine. However, the best solution is to use server side programming.

Comment: Thanks @www139 ...

Answer (score 3):

The second last thing you should do is passing users' passwords as plain text. The third last thing you should do is replacing password characters with javascript. Both of these allow unauthorized persons to reveal your user's password. But the very last thing you should do is storing users' passwords in your DB in plain form, which allows unathorized persons to obtain all of your users' passwords.

Even if you replace password characters on the server side and send it back in "p*******" form as the others have suggested, you give clear signal that you store your users' passwords in not-encrypted form, thus your site is more likely to be attacked.

Please have in mind that most, if not all bundles/frameworks provide user management support including at least basic password encryption by default, just like [FOSUserBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle).